# Where to place STL / template code c++?

Tags: c++, stl

Hi I have what is hopefully a quick question. As part of homework I've been asked to write my own template vector class (most of the code is there it just needs to be expanded upon). While I understand HOW it works and WHAT it does I have no idea WHERE to put the code or reference it as I have never seen it in context within a program.

Do I create a new cpp file with all this information in it, or do I just add it in above my main method? If I create a new file (either cpp or h) how do I reference it, with just a #include like normal?

This might seem fairly simple but I've tried creating a new .h file and then including it in my main program but I always get scope definition errors.

Comment: Put it in something like `my_vector.hpp`, and then whenever you want to use it in a `.cpp` file, `#include my_vector.hpp`.

Comment: Some code and a specific example would help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most compilers require you to put all the template code in a header file, rather than a source.  This is due to the way template expansion works.  You just include that header in whichever files need to use your vector class.

Some things to watch out for when creating a header:

1. Prevent multiple inclusion.  If your compiler supports `#pragma once` you can put that at the top, otherwise use the `#ifndef MY_HEADER_H .......` pattern.
2. Don't forget to put a semi-colon on the end of your class!!!!
3. Never put `using namespace whatever;` in the outer scope of a header (it's okay to use it within block scope such as `namespace something { ... }` or a function).
4. Be careful of name conflicts with `std::vector` if you are calling your class `vector` - make sure nobody has imported the `std` namespace prior to including your header.

Comment: Fixed your double underscore. That was bugging me.

Comment: I accepted this just because it  gave a bit of extra information. It turns out part of my problem was with one of the methods I have written declaration for which made the error list longer than I expected, seems to be working at the moment thank you very much!

Comment: Hahaha fair enough @chris - I'd hate to see how your temperament deals with a typical 20 year-old code base.

Comment: @paddy, At the moment, I have issues with refactoring code I take for personal use into my style instead of just leaving it. It probably takes a good chunk of what it would have to write it myself. And that's just style :p I'll need to get over it when I start working with code I can't just change on a whim to make slightly more correct (like the reserved identifier) because who knows what else I might break, and why waste whoever's paying's money to do *that*.

Comment: @paddy: "Never put using namespace whatever; in a header." - "Never" is too strong - it is perfectly fine if it's inside some scope (e.g. `namespace { using ... }`, `void f() { using ... }`) as it won't have ongoing impact after that scope.

Comment: That's right @TonyD ..  I guess I should have stated about putting it in the outer scope.  Will edit.

Answer (score 1):

One point you need to keep in mind is that you should place template declaration and definition together in the header file because of the compilation model of templates.

You can create a header file for the templated vector class and include this header file when you would like to use it in other `.h` or `.cpp` files.

You can also put them together inside `main`, but the previous option is better for you to maintain your code.